# How to write a javascript pretty time function

Tags: javascript

```
function local(a, b) {
    var c = b - a;
    if(c < 60) // seconds
    {
        document.write(Math.floor(c) + 'seconds ago');
    }
    else if(c >= 60 && c < 3600) // minutes
    {
        document.write(Math.floor(c/60) + 'minutes ago');
    }
    else if(c >= 3600 && c < 43200)  // hours
    {
        document.write(Math.floor(c/3600) + 'hours ago');
    }
    else if(c >= 43200) 
    {
        var d = new Date(a);
        document.write(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: In `elseif(c>=43200)`, it should be `else if(c>=43200)`.

Comment: Using document.write is not a good idea... http://www.sitepoint.com/insert-in-place-without-documentwrite/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate.  For example, instead of:

```
document.write('c/60 minutes ago');
```

Try this:

```
document.write((c / 60) + ' minutes ago');
```

If you want the output floored (rounded down):

```
document.write(Math.floor(c / 60) + ' minutes ago');
```

Comment: thanks I always get confused with the PHP '.' for concatenation

Comment: @Chris: As a side note, I prefer the `.` operator over `+` since it makes it clear that the requested operation is concatenation and not addition.  It helps disambiguate things like `"0" + 0`, which can mean any number of things depending on which language you are coding in.  The JavaScript equivalent of `x . y` is `x.toString() + y.toString()` since that converts both sides of the expression to strings, ensuring that concatenation is the only possible runtime interpretation.

Comment: `x.toString() + y.toString()` and `x + y` are 2 different things.

Comment: @Derek: That is exactly my point.  Read the rest of my comment.  The expression `x + y` can result in arithmetic addition, while the former expression cannot.